# Embedded pdfium in C++ application

Tags: c++, pdf, v8, chromium, pdfium

I'm currently trying to build a C++ application witch is able to convert PDF files to images.
I want to use [pdfium](https://code.google.com/p/pdfium/) to do this.

So I built pdfium as explain in the wiki and copied headers and generated libs in my cmake project.

When I try to build my application I get the following error:

```
src/include/pdfium-linux64/v8/include/libplatform/libplatform.h:8:33: fatal error: include/v8-platform.h: no such file or directory
```

In fact in this file there is:

```
#include "include/v8-platform.h"
```

But directories are like this:

```
include
| pdfium-linux64
| | v8
| | | include
| | | | libplatform
| | | | \ libplatform.h
| | | | v8-platform.h
| | | \ ...
| | \ ...
| \ ...
\ ...
```

So it could not work..

Does anyone have an idea of what to do to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [pdfshaver](https://github.com/documentcloud/pdfshaver) project, I found a solution:

- directly install pdfium through .deb package
- add gcc option:

> -I/usr/include/pdfium/v8
>    -L/usr/lib/pdfium
>   -lpthread
>   -lpdfium
>   -lfpdfapi
>   -lfxge
>   -lfdrm
>   -lfpdfdoc
>   -lfxcodec
>   -lfxcrt
>   -lfxedit
>   -lpdfwindow
>   -ljsapi
>   -lv8_libplatform
>   -lv8_snapshot
>   -lv8_base
>   -lv8_libbase
>   -licui18n
>   -licuuc
>   -licudata
>   -lformfiller
>   -lfpdftext
>   -lfpdfdoc
>   -lbigint
>   -ljavascript
>   -lpthread